# Export both Image file and String from SQLite database into Excel using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, sqlite, apache-poi

I am trying to export my SQLite database into a Excel file using Apache POI. I can export all string and double type values. But there have images(Blob files) on it. How can I export them together on the same Excel file and import them back?

Here is the code what I was implementing to store String and Double type values:

```
        String query = "select * from CarOwnerDB";
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Car Owner Details");
        XSSFRow header = sheet.createRow(0);

        header.createCell(0).setCellValue("Name");
        header.createCell(1).setCellValue("Username");
        header.createCell(2).setCellValue("Password");
        header.createCell(3).setCellValue("Company ID");
        header.createCell(4).setCellValue("NID");
        header.createCell(5).setCellValue("Bank Account Number");
        header.createCell(6).setCellValue("Bank Name");
        header.createCell(7).setCellValue("Permanent Address");
        header.createCell(8).setCellValue("Present Address");
        header.createCell(9).setCellValue("Phone");
        header.createCell(10).setCellValue("Email");
        header.createCell(11).setCellValue("Date Of Birth");
        header.createCell(12).setCellValue("Age");
        header.createCell(13).setCellValue("Gender");
        header.createCell(14).setCellValue("Maritial Status");
        header.createCell(15).setCellValue("Profile Picture");
        header.createCell(16).setCellValue("Balance");

        int index = 1;

        while (rs.next())
        {
            XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(index);
            row.createCell(0).setCellValue(rs.getString("name"));
            row.createCell(1).setCellValue(rs.getString("username"));
            row.createCell(2).setCellValue(rs.getString("password"));
            row.createCell(3).setCellValue(rs.getString("comID"));
            row.createCell(4).setCellValue(rs.getString("nid"));
            row.createCell(5).setCellValue(rs.getString("bankAccountNumber"));
            row.createCell(6).setCellValue(rs.getString("bankName"));
            row.createCell(7).setCellValue(rs.getString("permanentAddress"));
            row.createCell(8).setCellValue(rs.getString("presentAddress"));
            row.createCell(9).setCellValue(rs.getString("phone"));
            row.createCell(10).setCellValue(rs.getString("email"));
            row.createCell(11).setCellValue(rs.getString("dob"));
            row.createCell(12).setCellValue(rs.getInt("age"));
            row.createCell(13).setCellValue(rs.getString("gender"));
            row.createCell(14).setCellValue(rs.getString("maritialStatus"));
            row.createCell(15).setCellValue(rs.getBlob("profilePicture"));
            row.createCell(16).setCellValue(rs.getDouble("balance"));

            index++;
        }

        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(
                System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop/" + "Car Owner Database.xlsx");
        wb.write(fout);
        fout.close();

        preparedStatement.close();
        rs.close();
```

In the line

> row.createCell(15).setCellValue(rs.getBlob("profilePicture"));

I have image file. How can I store and retrieve those on the same Excel sheet?

Now I know how to get byte array with the image data from a SQL blob field. But don't know how to store them all using loop and array (To store string values here I used "XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(index)"). 
Now I am able to store one image file by implementing this code:

```
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream("a.png");
        byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
        int pictureIdx = wb.addPicture(bytes, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);
        is.close();
        CreationHelper helper = wb.getCreationHelper();
        XSSFSheet sheet1 = wb.createSheet("Car Owner Pictures");
        Drawing drawing = sheet1.createDrawingPatriarch();
        ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();
        anchor.setCol1(3);
        anchor.setRow1(2);
        Picture pict = drawing.createPicture(anchor, pictureIdx);
        pict.resize();

        String FileName = "Car Owner Database.xlsx";
        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(Main.getDirectory() + "/" + FileName);
        wb.write(fout);
        fout.close();
```

How can I add multiple images(same number I have created row)?

Comment: Did you try reading [the Apache POI documentation on Images](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Images)? And if not, what happens when you do?

Comment: I tried, but could not get how can I save both String and Image together. Could you please help me?

Comment: If String, store as string. If Image, store as Image. What's the issue?

Comment: The issue is, my file is in Blob format. When I am trying to store it, it's suggesting me to cast it as  File. Then when I am running it, it is getting this exception

`java.sql.SQLException: not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver
 at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4ResultSet.unused(JDBC4ResultSet.java:320)
 at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4ResultSet.getBlob(JDBC4ResultSet.java:345)`

on executing this line:

`InputStream is = new FileInputStream((File) rs.getBlob("profilePicture"));`


 I am unable to synchronize.  Sorry, still I can't get how to solve it :(

Comment: That isn't an Apache POI exception, it's a SQLite one! You either need to massively edit your question to include that, or ask a new one

Comment: Ok, then please tell me how can I insert images into number 15 cell (row.createCell(15)).

Comment: Images are **not** **in** cells in `Excel`. They are anchored on cells. And you need a byte array with the image data. See the link @Gagravarr gave you in the first comment. If you don't know how to get the byte array with the image data from a SQL blob field, please ask this concrete question.

Comment: @AxelRichter I have updated my question. Please let me know, now is it clear enough or not.